# Dynamically change link in views to html file

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to know if it is possible to change the link to html file in Django views. I have done enough googling but couldn't find any relevant stuff.
I have passed the slug in  tag in template like

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' slug="abc" %}"> test</a>
```

url.py

`path('(<slug>[\w-]+)/', views.article, name='detail'),`

in views.py

```
def article(request,slug):

return render(request, 'website/{slug}.html')
```

I want to render abc.html

Comment: This does not make much sense, this is the name of the *template*, not of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python string interpolation.

If your python version is greater then 3.6 you can use f-strings like:

```
return render(request, f'website/{slug}.html')
```

See the docs for python string interpolations: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a html suffix, you can do this in the path:

```
path('<slug:slug>.html', views.article, name='detail'),
```

The name of the *template* has nothing to do with the URI. The name of the template is just a file that is used to generate content that is passed as a response. So in the view, you will define a *template* (a file that specifies *how* to render the result), and this can have any name, since it does not map on the URI:

```
def article(request,slug):
    return render(request, 'app_name/template.html')
```

It is however not very Django-ish to add a `.html` suffix. The idea is about making pleasant looking URIs, not fill these with "noise".